# Google+ interactive post popup disappears after 0,5 sec

Tags: javascript, popup, google-plus

I'm creating this page http://kokas.x10.mx/?page_id=2 where I aim to send invitations through social media. The Google+ popup is my problem. Click on the google plus image, sign into google and the popup will magically disappear very very fast...you just get a glimpse of it for half a second. What causes this behavior? my html for the button is

```
<button
  id="googleInvite"
  class="g-interactivepost"
  data-contenturl="http://fray.it"
  data-clientid="xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
  data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin"
  data-prefilltext="Join me on Fray and get help from amazing local people!"
  data-calltoactionlabel="INVITE"
  data-calltoactionurl="http://kokas.x10.mx/?page_id=2">
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/google.png" alt="Google+" /><span>Google+</span>
</button>
```

Is it possible to check the javascripts that run while this is happening with the browser's dev tools? I have been following instructions here https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a call to action url that has a different domain from the content url.  You need to be able to serve them both from the same domain.

Comment: Spotted this myself and changed it but didn't work. I set those 2 URLs to "http://kokas.x10.mx", "kokas.x10.mx", "http://kokas.x10.mx/?page_id=2", but none worked. BUT, Google's button on this page https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/interactive DOES work correctly, so I must have something else typed wrongly.

Comment: I think I found the answer..my hosting provider is banned! I was doing continuous Ctrl+PrntScr to catch a little message that appears instantly on clicking the button and it says "Claimed origin not in whitelist: http://kokas.x10.mx"